# Customize List's cells in DashCode

Tags: macos, list, dashcode

I have my site created with Dashcode and I am using the List object but I don't like the default blue background when a cell is selected.
How can I customize this? For example change it to grey or white, etc.

(As far as i know, everything is customizable in Dashcode, is just sometimes you have to do it using code and not Dashcode UI.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my self:

looking at main.css I found something like:

```
.listRowTemplate_template.selected {
    background-color: rgb(56, 0, 217);
}
```

Which is the color I want to change ;)

Answer (score 1):

Which would have been my answer, shall i vote you up? ;-)

It is easy to forget that when in Dashcode it is "just" JavaScript, CSS and HTML and so many problems will often succumb to those type of solutions such as you have done.